# javascript: how do i make my own testing module?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to make my own version of jfiddle. I found that it was easy to do with html but with javascript i'm having some trouble.

this is my current code:

```
<script>
var code;
var jscode;
function makeHTMLcode(code){
    document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = code;
}
function makeJScode(jscode){
    $(function() {
    document.getElementById("jstester").innerHTML ="<sc"+"ript>" + jscode + "</"+"script>";
    });
}
</script>

<div class="htmlTester"><textarea onkeyup="makeHTMLcode(this.value);"></textarea></div>
<div class="output">
 <div style="height:100%;background-color:white; border:1px solid gray;">
  <div id="body"></div>
  <div id="jscode"></div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="JSTester"><textarea onkeyup="makeJScode(this.value);" ></textarea></div>
```

the html code goes with onkeyup to the output screen and works right away. the javascript however doesn't load its new functions. When i use the document.write function, the whole page reloads but my new made functions work. when i use the current code nothing loads.

So how can i output my new javascript functions?

Comment: Have a look at the way jsFiddle does it, if you really want to replicate it. Hint: `iframe` is the key to the problem. You will *need* to reload the page, otherwise the old functions would still have their effect.

Comment: Not if you want them sandboxed. Which you do, by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to set are the `type` (to "text/javascript") and `text` attributes.

This works if you paste it to your console on this page:

```
// Create an iframe and append it to your document
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.height = 400;
iframe.width = 600;
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

// Use this to append your HTML into the iframe
iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = 
    '<div id="test">This is my iFrame</div>';

// Create an script block and append it to your iframe to sandbox it
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.text = "document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'This is cool!'";
iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Regarding the discussion in comments, I agree that you'll want to use an iframe for this, as you'll have to sandbox the JS and CSS so that there are no conflicts with the other JS & CSS controlling your page.

Comment: this worked thanks :) do you have an example of how i could use iframes to achieve this? because i cant simply use document.getElementById("iframe").innerHTML = code;

Comment: Edited to demonstrate how to do this with an iframe

Comment: One last edit, to properly append the script to the iframe's body, and demonstrate it working on the HTML.

Comment: i just noticed the script issue! by the way, is it possible to give the iframe a class that i can place in my css how big im making it? i want the values in percentages. (my javascript is not that good yet. focused a lot on php)

Comment: Yes, you can style the iframe however you want, using a class or an id.  In fact, you probably don't even have to create it dynamically.